# Expressing logic symbols as words

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Im having a bit of trouble expressing the following into words. The question follows:
Consider the propositional values:
$p\left(​n\right): ​n \text{​ is prime} $
$q\left(​n\right): ​n ​\text{ is even} $
$r\left(​n\right): ​n ​>2$
Express the following in words:

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z} \left[\left(r\left(n\right)\land p\left(n\right)\right)  ⇒ \sim q\left(n\right)\right]$$

So far I have: For all n's that are integers, if both n is greater than 2 and prime then n cannot be even.

I know what the symbols mean, but I'm not sure what words are deemed appropriate for statements. Thanks!

Comment: Please use Mathjax for rendering the math https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Looks good to me. I would only change ''if $n$ is both greater...''. For the rest I'd write essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to read this statement would be:

for all integers $n$, if $n$ is greater than $2$ and is prime then $n$ is not even.